# Let $γ$ be a counter-clockwise path around the unit circle centred at zero. Compute the path integral$\int \frac{(z+1)^{2020}}{z}dz$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$\int \frac{(z+1)^{2020}}{z}dz$

My solution :

The path is a closed circle of centre $a = 0$ , radius, $ r=1$ so $ C(a,r) = C(0,1)$ so using Cauchy's integral formula,
let $f(z) = (z+1)^{2020}$ and $\frac {1}{(z-w)} = 1/z \implies w= 0$ hence solution is

$2\pi if(0) = 2\pi i (1) ^{2020} = 2\pi i $

Is my solution correct?

Comment: yes it is $2\pi i$ (which you can also see by expanding $(z+1)^{2020}$ using the binomial theorem and integrating stuff term-by-term; because the polynomial part will integrate to $0$, and the only contribution comes from $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\,dz$)